# Patent citation

Tags: citation, patet

I wonder if it legal to use a procedure of a patent as a procedure in my research as it is! or otherwise, should I modify it and cite the patent with mentioning the paper? If it is legal, How can I cite a patent its researchers name in Chinese?

Comment: Can you tell us the country the patent is issued in and the country you are doing the research in?

Comment: You might want to search our answers using the keyword "research exception" or "research exemption". This answer might be relevant. https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18706/using-patents-for-research/18730#18730

Comment: As for citation rules where an author's name is in a foreign language, it would be no different than citing any document written in a foreign language and off topic for this site. Perhaps Academia SE (https://academia.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you could provide us the actual patent number, we can check to see if there are equivalent patents in other countries.